# Multiparts to singleparts to error - QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-2.14, splitting

I work with this polygon and I try to use the vector tool "Singleparts to Multipart" in order to expload the layer to  multipart, so I can select each part seperatly.

I don't care if the features in the attribute table has the same value. All I want is exploded layer:

[image]
[image]

and I get this error:

[image]
[image]

"At Least two features must contain the same attribute value"

I read [Producing singlepart featureclass with unique IDs for each spatially non-connected polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32727/producing-singlepart-featureclass-with-unique-ids-for-each-spatially-non-connect) ,but didn't get an answer

Comment: Function is trying to find polygons which have the same "myid" value and combine them into multipolygon. Feels like a bug to use term "Unique ID field" in the UI. It might rather be called as "grouping field". If you want to combine all polygons into one multipolygon add a new attribute and fill it with same values. Depending on your use case the dissolve tool may also be usable http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123722/singleparts-to-multipart-vs-dissolve.

Comment: i want to create a lot of features and not create one single feature.

Comment: Does it mean **Multipart to singleparts**?

Comment: i think this is the tool i need

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong tool. If you want o "explode" multipart features so that you can edit them separately, then you must use the "multipart to single part tool" or use the [Multipart Split Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/splitmultipart/).

Comment: this tool only create temporary layer , but in the attribute table there only one row instead of two rows

Comment: @newGIS Could you expound a little more on what was the problem? With all due respect, I feel there is small misunderstanding about the tool's behavior. It's advantage and how-to can be found [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/multipartsplit) (direct link) or through the repository page in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error comment: "At Least two features must contain the same attribute value". For example, if it is used the FID field in the "Singlepart to multipart" tool, for shapefile of next image, I got "Invalid unique ID field".

[image]

On the other hand, when the "values" field was used, the shapefile named "Multipart" was produced without any problem.

[image]

It can be observed that the attributes table of Multipart shapefile has only one record because "value" field has only one value: 15.