# Joining more than two lines that intersected in one point using FME

Tags: line, intersection, attribute-joins, fme-transformer

i have point connects with four lines  in dgn file 
Each line has his unique id ,iam usng FME 2018 software

i used line combiner for the map ,i found only ,each two lines is able to connect together .but when more than two line are intersecting in one point , line combiner will not able to connect them .

i tried a lot for some days but it does not work .

Do you have a suggestion for how I can do that using FME?

Comment: I am not familiar with FME, but it seems that if you were to connect more than one line it would no longer be a line. I know that you can have multipart polygons, but I am not sure if multipart lines is a thing. Are you sure that you want them "connected" or just grouped together. You might consider preforming a buffer and dissolve to convert them if you need them to be physically connected.

Comment: i need them to be connected. line combiner is able only to do connect only two lines not more so i did the process two times but it does not work .i thought ,it will connect first time two lines then next time will connect all of them but it was wrong idea ,about multi part ,i do not have an transformer called multi part line or what u mean .u think if i did buffer then dissolve then ,it will be connected .could i ask what buffer exactly able to do .thanks for reply

Comment: These features and functionality may not be available in FME and may have to be done in a GIS product like ArcMap, ArcGIS Pro or QGIS. If you can do it I would recommend that you establish a common id via the points to the lines. Then preform a dissolve function. I am not sure this can be done using FME. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32727/producing-singlepart-featureclass-with-unique-ids-for-each-spatially-non-connect

Comment: @AvidDabbler multipart polygons, lines and points are all things.  To see the multipart points or lines just select two with a common value in one field and dissolve on that field.

Comment: If you want to try doing this in Python, then to ask about that please use a separate question in which you present a code attempt.

Comment: i did another topic as u suggested but they closed the topic bcs as the manager said,i have to try first to do then ppl. here are able to  solve but i have no experience with python to do it ,i am using only FME but i am  not able to find transformer to do what i want but FME supports also python caller so if i do in python i can add the script to my program in side FME,The issue exactly i have dgn file it looks like the map it has many different lines some are intersected some not ,i need every line intersected in one point to be connected please if you can help me .write here and thanks alot

Comment: The other question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349156/merging-more-than-two-lines-that-intersected-in-one-point-using-python-with-fme) was closed because in it you asked about Python but did not include a code attempt.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of what you're attempting. It is most certainly possible to do with FME, but I want to be sure of what you're attempting.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, the LineCombiner can't put all 4 lines into 1 because they would not really be a line then.  In FME Lingo, you need to "aggregate" the 4 lines into a multi-part line, which can then be saved to most GIS/SpatialDatabase systems as a multi geometry.

You'd do this by first ensuring your point(s) have some kind of unique ID on them. The Counter xformer can do this for you if they didn't already.  Then run the points and the lines into a PointOnLineOverlayer. Be sure to turn on Attribute Accumulation, which will transfer the point ID over to the Lines when they overlap. Any lines that come out that have a point ID should then be routed into an Aggregator, grouping by Point ID.  Bob's your uncle...

[image: Screenshot of Sample Workspace]